# Are constructors optional in Java or what?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm a C# programmer trying to hack at a Java project. Here's an anonymized extract from our production code. It works (I think). Note that this *is* the whole class.

```
public class Y extends X
{
  public Z m_Z;

  protected void readCustomData (CustomStream reader, boolean forUpdate)
    throws IOException, FTGException
  {
    super.readCustomData (reader, forUpdate) ;
    m_Z.readBinaryData (reader, forUpdate) ;
  }

  protected void writeCustomData (CustomStream writer, int original)
    throws IOException, FTGException
  {
    super.writeCustomData (writer, original) ;
    m_Z.writeBinaryData (writer, original) ;
  }
}
```

What puzzles me is - where is `m_Z` initialized? I cannot find it in the entire codebase. So why don't the `readCustomData` and `writeCustomData` methods fail with `NullReferenceException` - or whatever the equivalent is in Java? Is `m_Z` somehow automagically constructed along with `Y`? Or have I missed something after all and there is some deeper magic in the codebase which initializes it?

Comment: What kind of IDE do you use? Within eclipse for example you can search for references within your workspace with marking that field and pressing strg+shift+g. Most IDEs have something simular. That way you should find your nasty initilizer! ;)

Comment: Netbeans. And I already searched for it, both by references and simply by string. But I already found out that reflection was used to initialize it, so it wasn't found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a Java class does not declare a constructor, the compiler implicitly adds a no-argument constructor that does nothing but call the superclass no-argument constructor (if there is none such, there will be a compiler error).

However, in your example the field `m_Z` would be null. If calls to those method succeed, then the field must be set elsewhere. It is public, after all (very bad practice).

Comment: Beat me to it, and great point about the public field.  Talk about a code smell.

Comment: Code smell no doubt, but that's besides the point. Let's just say that's the least of code smells in that project. :) Anyways, thanks for the clarification. I'll continue my hunt then.

Comment: I don't remember the last time I used a public variable.  Maybe never.

Answer (score 0):

m_Z is public, so it can be initialised outside the class:

```
Y y = new Y();
y.m_Z = new Z();
y.readCustomData(...);
```

Would work OK.

Horrible code though.

Answer (score 0):

`m_Z` variable is `public`. Is there a chance that someone from outside sets it? Although this is a pretty bad practice...

Answer (score 0):

If you have no constructor, java creates a default constructor for you. All members are initialized with the given value or, if no value is given, with `null`. That means, if your member `m_Z` is set, it was set from somewhere else (it's a public member), because the default constructor has initialized `m_Z` with null;

Answer (score 0):

In the code given m_Z is never initialized, so it is null. But it can be accessed from outrside (public), so the value can be set by `y.m_Z = ...`.